# Display results based on the duration a customer was present in the shop in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document which has a start date and end date of when the customer was present in office. I need to sort documents based on the time the customer was present in the shop. How is it possible using elasticsearch?

Comment: Please add your code to the question to help us help you!

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality you can use Script Based Sorting, docs can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html).

```
"sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "script" : "doc['fieldName_endDate'].value - doc['fieldName_startDate'].value",
            "type" : "date",
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
```

This will sort the values returned by the rest of the query by the least to most time spent in the shop.